# Task_InternalError Cannot index into a null array in SSIS Deploy VSTS task run on deployment group phase

Tags: ssis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am working DevOps with VSTS. Currently I worked on SSIS package deployment through VSTS release for that I used the “**[SSIS Deploy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TG.VSTS-SSIS)**” task but right now this extension is not available in VSTS market place.

Configuration of SSIS Deploy task at VSTS release level:
[image]

The SSIS Deploy task will be worked if I run this task using **Agent phase** with the Private Agent. But whenever the same task run using **Deployment group phase** with specified tags, at that time I am facing the issue like

> Task_InternalError Cannot index into a null array.

For suppose, If I used [SSISDeployPackage](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=automagically.SSISDeployPackage) task instead of **SSIS Deploy** task then how to pass the project parameters.

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve the above issue?

Comment: Did you meet the same error when using SSISDeployPackage task? And can you show the release logs for using private agent (successful) and deployment group (failed) separately?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT,  When I Used SSISDeployPackage task I am getting the error like "SSISDB catalog doesn't exist, can you create it manually" even I already created Catalog folder under SQL Server Integration Services.

Comment: These are release logs for private agent  https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-JUB9_wu9CwhwamvxjbAHu0qkD and Deployment group phase https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-JUB9_wu9CwhvAo-k2xNTQ2XO3

Answer (score 1):

To trouble shooting the issue for deploy with deployment group, please check with below aspects:

1. Make sure the target machine of the deployment group is the local machine where your SQL Server database located.
2. Make sure the service for the deployment group is logged with the same user name which you can access to your database.

   As below example, the user name to log on the service for deployment group target machine is `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`, you should change the account as your user name instead (such as `domain\username`), and then restart the service.

   [image]

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the SSIS Deploy task is attempting to access your Integration Service Catalogs. If you have none created, the task throws a 'Cannot index into a null array' error.

To fix this just create an Integration Service Catalog called SSISDB in your target SQL Server before running the SSIS Deploy task.